# How come visual studio still rebuild the whole solution when I only clean one of the project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I notice that when I clean on the the project in my solution (The project is not the parent project. That is, no project depends on it), I still see Visual Studio rebuild the whole solution.

Do you guys see something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this project depend on the other projects that are being rebuilt?  There are two options in the IDE:  Clean, and Project Only => Clean.  The former cleans the project and all of its dependencies.  The latter cleans only the project itself.

Comment: I used the later one but still rebuild a lot of other projects. The project that I clean depends on other projects but other projects don't depend on it.

Comment: @Kintarō: I rather think you accidentally used the first Clean, because otherwise they wouldn't all rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Clean" in Visual Studio cleans *anything* related to the build of the project being targeted. As a result, all things required to build that specific project will have to be rebuilt.

Edit: this macro may or may not work to provide you with a solution to your desire: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318651#appliesto

Answer (score 0):

Since one of your projects changed, it's also understandable that projects that depend on it have changed, and thus need a rebuild.

If you change only the top level project, the dependencies don't get messed with so they don't need to be rebuilt. You got it all wrong.